# Error when downloading file from amazon s3

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to download files from amazon s3. I am using .NET sdk for that. I have written down follwong code:

```
GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest()
    .WithKey("abc/xyz.jpg")
    .WithBucketName(appConfig);

using (GetObjectResponse response = s3Client.GetObject(request))
{
    int numBytesToRead = (int)response.ContentLength;
    if (numBytesToRead > 0)
    {
        int numBytesRead = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte32768;
        using (FileStream fstream = new FileStream(@"C:\abc\xyz.jpg", FileMode.Create))
        {
            using (Stream responseStream = response.ResponseStream)
            {
                do
                {
                    numBytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    fstream.Write(buffer, 0, numBytesRead);
                }
                while (numBytesRead > 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this code I am able to download file. But now I want to download multiple files. For that first I am listing down all the files which are available on s3 and then store it in arraylist and after that call my download function for each file.

After running list file method when I call download function after using (GetObjectResponse response = s3Client.GetObject(request)) I get exception.

{"Access Denied"}

```
Stack trace:
at Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client.processRequestError(String actionName, HttpWebRequest request, WebException we, HttpWebResponse errorResponse, String requestAddr, WebHeaderCollection& respHdrs, Type t, Exception& cause)
at Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client.handleHttpWebErrorResponse(S3Request userRequest, WebException we, HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse httpResponse, Exception& cause, HttpStatusCode& statusCode)
at Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client.getResponseCallback[T](IAsyncResult result)
at Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client.endOperation[T](IAsyncResult result)
at Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client.EndGetObject(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client.GetObject(GetObjectRequest request)
at ScreenshotsUploader.ScreenshotsUploader.downloadFile(AmazonS3 s3Client, NameValueCollection appConfig) in c:\Users\xyz\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ScreenshotsUploader\ScreenshotsUploader\ScreenshotsUploader.cs:line 220
at ScreenshotsUploader.ScreenshotsUploader.GetServiceOutput() in c:\Users\xyz\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ScreenshotsUploader\ScreenshotsUploader\ScreenshotsUploader.cs:line 55
```

Status code:

System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden

What do I need to do to fix this?

I have also tried different approach to download file and got the same error:

Second approach:

```
string fileToDownload = @"xyzjpg";
string saveToo = @"C:\xyz.jpg";
TransferUtilityDownloadRequest request = new TransferUtilityDownloadRequest().WithBucketName(appConfig).WithKey(fileToDownload).WithFilePath(saveToo);
TransferUtility tu = new TransferUtility(s3Client);
tu.Download(request);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you include your bucket policy? what kind of permissions does your  IAM have on the bucket?

Comment: This looks like it may be a permission issue.  If not, can you post your actual code?  I just see string literals for file name, object keys etc.

Comment: I haven't changed(add/edit) anything in Permission and policy. I have just created bucket and upload files to bucket.

Comment: IN both the approach I am able to download file(single file). Is there any other way I can download all the files?

Comment: You specify your aws credentials while instantiating S3Client. May be reusing that object is creating this problem. Can you try and see what happens if in each iteration (while traversing the arraylist) you create and pass a new S3Client to your single file download function.

Comment: Thanks Harshal for your suggestion. It worked. I have not created S3client for each iteration but I just created new s3client in beginning of my downloadFile method and it worked.

Answer (score 5):

```
public Stream DownloadS3Object(string awsBucketName, string keyName)
{

    using (var client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client())
    {
        Stream imageStream = new MemoryStream();
        GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest { BucketName = awsBucketName, Key = keyName };
        using (GetObjectResponse response = client.GetObject(request))
        {
            response.ResponseStream.CopyTo(imageStream);
        }
        imageStream.Position = 0;
        // Clean up temporary file.
        // System.IO.File.Delete(dest);
        return imageStream;
    }
}
```

pass the value in function get stream path save it in folder with use of below.

```
SaveStreamToFile(foldername + "/", MainStreamAwsPath);
```

and than you can apply simple c# code to download that folder.